# SVG Animation how to animate stroke-dasharray more than one time?

Tags: css, animation, svg

Here i have a code of svg of a cube. I want to cube draw  it self so i used property *stroke-dasharray stroke-dashoffset & @keyframes* . it Works nicely.
But how can i use stroke-dasharray property again so that after drawing cube itself it become dashed.
*By dashed i mean the stroke line of cube is dashed (after cube drawn itself).*
Also is there any way to use gradient color in stroke.
Thnx :)

```css
path{
 fill:none;
 stroke:#000;
 stroke-width:5.3583231;
 stroke-linecap:butt;
 stroke-linejoin:round;
 stroke-miterlimit:4;
 stroke-opacity:1;
 
}

#path1, #path2{
 stroke-dasharray: 250;
 stroke-dashoffset: 250;
 animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}

#path3, #path4, #path5, #path6{
 stroke-dasharray: 30;
 stroke-dashoffset: 30;
 animation: dash 1.5s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 4.2s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<svg
   
   width="100px"
   height="100px"
   viewBox="0 0 100 100"
   id="SVGRoot"
   >

  <g
     id="layer1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     inkscape:label="Layer 1">
    <path
       d="M 3.2591993,33.714927 50.169441,65.506007 96.63155,33.70475 50.184339,2.8402629 Z"
       id="path1" class="effect"
       />
    <path
       d="M 50.186433,97.029056 96.631513,65.270332 50.169441,33.815733 3.2620141,65.545471 Z"
       id="path2" class="effect"
        />
    <path
       d="m 3.2591993,33.714927 0.00299,31.830544"
       id="path3" class="effect"
        />
    <path
       d="m 50.169441,65.506007 0.01697,31.523049"
       id="path4" class="effect"
        />
    <path
       d="m 96.63155,33.70475 -3.7e-5,31.565582"
       id="path5" class="effect"
        />
    <path
       d="M 50.184339,2.8402629 50.16944,33.815733"
       id="path6" class="effect"
        />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You'll need to explain exactly what you mean by "it become dashed".

Comment: Change the `stroke-dasharray` value to something small on the end of animation? Like `stroke-dasharray: 2;`